# SQL Server - Grouping a column and select Top 1 value from the other column based on the column, which is not included in the T-Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called `Product` which contains this data:

```
ParentProduct   Product   Runs  Units
-------------------------------------
    1               5      8     6
    1               5      8     6 
    1               3      7    10
    1               3      8    10
    2               4      8     5
    2               4      8     5
```

Now I want the grouped runs based on `ParentProduct` and `Product` grouping. The result would be:

```
Runs   Units
------------
8       16
8        5
7       10
```

That means, internally our logic should group based on `ParentProduct` and `Product` and should produce the SUM of Units.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post what you have done so far (your sql code)

Comment: Against ParentProduct - Product, 1 - 3 you have runs 7 & 8, why do you want to end up with just 7 (and not 8)?

Comment: If it's sum by ParentProduct, Product, why 1, 5 returns 8 16???  Shouldn't it be 16 12?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @products table(ParentProduct int, Product int, Runs int, Units int)
    insert into @products 
        select 1,   5,  8,  6 union all
        select 1,   5,  8,  6 union all
        select 1,   3,  7,  10 union all
        select 1,   3,  8,  10 union all
        select 2,   4,  8,  5 union all
        select 2,   4,  8,  5

select runs, units = sum(units)
from(
    select ParentProduct, product, runs, units = sum(distinct units)
    from @products
group by ParentProduct, product, runs) t
group by ParentProduct, runs
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time. But I want to handle dynamic data instead of Hardcoded value.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping on `Runs` & `ParentProduct` for the unique tupples will also get that expected result.

```
SELECT Runs, SUM(Units) as Units
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ParentProduct, Product, Runs, Units 
    FROM Product
) AS p
GROUP BY Runs, ParentProduct
ORDER BY Runs DESC, ParentProduct ASC;
```